# Amazon EC2 API and Windows instances - any way to get drive letter assignment?

Tags: .net, windows, amazon-ec2

I have Windows EC2 instances that I am managing via a C# application; I'm using the AWS.NET SDK.  I'm trying to figure out from the documentation if there is anyway to query the API and get the volume-to-drive letter assignment within the instances.  Failing that, does anyone know if EC2 is consistent in its mapping of devicenames (e.g. /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc) to drive letter?  Will /dev/sdb always be D, /dev/sdc always be E, etc.?

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe helpful: I have an app that runs on multiple EC2 instances. The app simply moves all of its work to another EC2 store when finished. No need to peer into the instance that way.

Comment: My problem is that I need to know (for purposes of later configuration information) what drive letters ended up with which volume requests; I have an app that needs to know those paths, and I can't wait for the instance to complete booting to find out.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, unless you go in and mess with it, the drives map out, Device Name to Drive Letter, like so:

```
/dev/sda1 C:
/dev/sda2 D:

/dev/xdf F:
/dev/xdg G:
/dev/xdh H:
...etc
```

I have no idea how to tell it to map something to E... and I've never cared to.

So as long as you let everything be the defaults, you'll get the above consistently and can easily get that Device mapping from a DescribeInstances call.

Answer (score -1):

The EC2 API is to control the virtualized environment only (ie. launch machine, snapshot machine, terminate etc.) So it is completely independent of the underlying OS, and therefore it won't give machine specific details like drive mappings. It may be better to 'hack' the application so that the underlying drive letters are not a problem.

Comment: There are other APIs that provide specific OS-level things (like to get the auto-generated password of the instance). Also, the disk specifiers for Unix VMs are exactly the names represented in the volume request (e.g. /dev/sdc becomes /dev/sdc in the Linux instance).  I'm just looking for equivalent functionality (windows volume IDs if not mount points)

Comment: Good point about some low-level OS capabilities... However, I am only aware of such access being made available to get the machine to launch (eg. passwords), but not for more generic OS level information. I may be wrong...